# Syntax regarding variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've recently been asked to modify some powershell scripts, and I've a good understanding of the concept with variables and $. But I don't quite understand what this piece of code does and works:

```
[string]$env = $(throw "-env is required.)
```

To be more precise I wonder about the single $ sign, and the throw keyword.

/Andy

Answer (score 4):

It is being used to make the $env parameter mandatory. `[env]$env = "default"` will assign "default" to env if no value is provided.

`throw "error"` is used to throw an exception.

Therefore `[string]$env = $(throw "-env is required.")`

will throw an exception if no value is provided by the user.

Comment: But wouldn't it be much cleaner to write something like this for making a parameter mandatory:
[code]
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$env,
[/code]

Comment: @Andy.l Yes, it would.

Comment: @Andy.l - Yes it would, although I don't think `mandatory` was available in powershell 1.0 so it could be an old script, or the author was unaware of `mandatory`.

Comment: Using `mandatory=$true` would make the function prompt for missing arguments. Maybe if you didn't want the prompting you would use the default argument trick, but mandatory is generally better all round.